# "A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I am using the following code.

```
$request->hour= 10:00:00
$parameters->hour=strtotime(date(" H:i:s",$request->hour));
```

I am getting the following error.

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

Answer (score 2):

Try `$parameters->hour=date("H:i:s",strtotime($request->hour));`

or if you want `$parameters->hour=strtotime(date("H:i:s",strtotime($request->hour)));`

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to try this:

```
$hour = "10:00:00";
$parameters->hour = strtotime(date("H:i:s",strtotime($hour)));
```

or you can use carbon

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($hour)->format("H:i:s");
```